# Multiple line JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, lines, jtextpane, fileinputstream

So I have been starting to work on an encyclopedia as a project for college and I'm coming over an issue. I am trying to import a .txt file to print my text to my text panel but the problem is, I can't print paragraphs and it only prints one line.
My textpanel code is the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class GTAIntro extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public GTAIntro() {
    setSize(800,800);
    setLayout(null);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("");
    button_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Facultate\\anul 2\\Java Workspace\\Encyclopedia\\src\\icons\\back.png"));
    button_1.setEnabled(false);
    button_1.setBounds(10, 700, 50, 50);
    add(button_1);

    JButton button = new JButton("");
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Facultate\\anul 2\\Java Workspace\\Encyclopedia\\src\\icons\\next.png"));
    button.setBounds(740, 700, 50, 50);
    add(button);

    JLabel rockstarlogo = new JLabel("");
    rockstarlogo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Facultate\\anul 2\\Java Workspace\\Encyclopedia\\src\\icons\\gta\\rockstar-logo.png"));
    rockstarlogo.setBounds(10, 11, 150, 150);
    add(rockstarlogo);

    JTextArea textpanel = new JTextArea();
    textpanel.setLineWrap(true);
    textpanel.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textpanel.setEditable(false);
    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\Facultate\\anul 2\\Java Workspace\\Encyclopedia\\src\\text\\gta\\gtaintro.txt");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            textpanel.setText(strLine);
        }
    in.close();
    }catch(Exception e){System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}
    textpanel.setBounds(100, 222, 593, 528);
    add(textpanel);

}
}
```

Comment: Neither Eclipse nor WindowBuilder have *anything* To do with this problem!  BTW - Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JEditorPane.read(InputStream,Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#read%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.Object%29) - much easier.  Perhaps something like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


public class GTAIntro extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public GTAIntro() {
    setSize(800,800);
    setLayout(null);

    JTextArea textpanel = new JTextArea();
    textpanel.setLineWrap(true);
    textpanel.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textpanel.setEditable(false);
    try{
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("D:\\Facultate\\anul 2\\Java Workspace\\Encyclopedia\\src\\text\\gta\\gtaintro.txt");
        // do not use DataInputStream to read text
        // DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(fstream);
        textpanel.read(reader, fstream);
    }catch(Exception e){System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}
    textpanel.setBounds(100, 222, 593, 528);
    add(textpanel);

    JButton button_1 = new JButton("");
    button_1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Facultate\\anul 2\\Java Workspace\\Encyclopedia\\src\\icons\\back.png"));
    button_1.setEnabled(false);
    button_1.setBounds(10, 700, 50, 50);
    add(button_1);

    JButton button = new JButton("");
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Facultate\\anul 2\\Java Workspace\\Encyclopedia\\src\\icons\\next.png"));
    button.setBounds(740, 700, 50, 50);
    add(button);

    JLabel rockstarlogo = new JLabel("");
    rockstarlogo.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D:\\Facultate\\anul 2\\Java Workspace\\Encyclopedia\\src\\icons\\gta\\rockstar-logo.png"));
    rockstarlogo.setBounds(10, 11, 150, 150);
    add(rockstarlogo);

}
}
```

Comment: The method read(Reader, Object) in the type JTextComponent is not applicable for the arguments (DataInputStream, FileInputStream)

Comment: My bad.  I forgot to mention earlier.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  That code I posted was not tested locally here.  Post an SSCCE of your best attempt, and I'll correct it.

Comment: I did post my code, this is only a part of my program as the other part is too big to post here.

Comment: Try the code in the edit.  Note that it compiles cleanly, but since it has no `main(..)` and I have no text files here, I could not actually confirm it 'works as advertised'.

Comment: Note the code in the edit still has many problems, starting with the layouts.  I chose to alter *only* the code relevant to the question.

Comment: It's working, thank you. What problems are you talking about?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What problems are you talking about?

Comment: 1) The first was mentioned in a comment to the question.  2) Using hard coded paths to files, for what will likely be embedded-resources by the time of deployment.  3) Ignoring the stack trace (more useful than the message) in the `catch`..

Answer (score 0):

```
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");    
textpanel.setText(strLine + newLine);
```

Comment: This is simply a statement that doesn't actually serve to answer the original poster's question. I suggest you read over [**how to answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and expand it.